# How to send message to admin when fails login in 3 attemps

Tags: php

I have used the following code to send the message to admin when a user enters the wrong username and password for three times.

Please help me to debug the problem in this code. How do I send a message to the admin in following code?

```
<?php
   session_start();
   $cookie_var_attempts=0;

   if(isset($_POST['username']))
   {
     $uname=$_POST['username'];
     $password=$_POST['password'];
     mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
     mysql_select_db('gps_test1');
     $sql="select * from tbl_user where uname='$uname' and password='$password'";
     $query=mysql_query($sql);
     $no_of_rows=mysql_num_rows($query);

     if($no_of_rows==1)
     {  
        $_SESSION['username']=$uname;           
        header('location:track_map.php');               
     }                   
     else                               
     {
        if($cookie_var_attempts>=3)
        {
           echo"message is sent to admin";
        }
        else
        {   
           echo "Enter the correct username and password";   
           $cookie_var_attempts++;
        }
     }
   }
?>
```

Comment: Are you getting errors on code that had worked previously?

Comment: You have not used any php mailing function. Preferably I'd suggest logging the error in database, which the admin can monitor from time to time

Comment: Your duplicate earlier question from just 6 hours ago - [How to send message to admin when user fails login in 3 attemps using php](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19111914/367456) - has been put On Hold for a Reason - Do not duplicate you own question. Instead edit the previous one to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a specific idea in mind of HOW you want to send the message?

And easy way is to use email.

Something like:

```
if($cookie_var_attempts>=3)
{
    $to = "soandso@domain.com";
    $subject = "Bad login";
    $body = "$body";

    if (!mail($to, $subject, $body))
    {
        echo 'Could not send email.';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the data in `$_SESSION` if not the variable will always has zero value.

For example instead of `$cookie_var_attempts=0;` use:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['attemps']) $_SESSION['attemps'] = 0;
```

And change the references to the `$cookie_var_attempts` variable for `$_SESSION['attemps']`

To send a message to the user you can use [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function.

I think this is what you need right?

Answer (score 0):

A) MYSQL_ is deprecated, use mysqli or pdo
B) you're only checking to see if a particular computer is logging in unsuccessfully 3 times, while useful at preventing some attacks, it doesn't provide much info, nor does it allow you to lock particular accounts from being hacked. Further, a user could just dump the cookie and keep trying. If you're going to use that method as well, use sessions and a $_SESSION variable.

So my solution:

1) Make a method that validates that the user they are trying to log in as exists. DO NOT TELL THE END USER IF IT DOESN'T EXIST, just use a generic error. 
2) add a field to the user table that stores the number of incorrect logins since last log in, check to see if that number is greater than 3 after validating that the user exists. increment this number for every failed login for the user, reset it to 0 on a correct log in.

3) finally, use the mail method to send an email if it fails the check in step 2.